# Consuming a wcf service with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf

So I'm trying to use a json to consume a wcf service. What I want it to do, is to take the values from a simple html form, and assign those values through json into an object instanced in the wcf. Since I wasn't able to do so, I tried yo narrow it as much as I could, so you can (maybe) help me out with this. Now, just to know if it works, I want the wcf service to answer an ok string.

Here is my html/js code

```
   function saveSection() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:52928/SectionService.svc/Guardar",
            data: '{"name": "' + sectionName.value + '", "title": "' + sectionTitle.value + '", "scope": "' + sectionScope.value + '",  "description": "' + sectionDescription.value + '"}',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () { alert('it works') },
            error: function () { alert('it doesnt work') },
            contentType: "application/json",

        });
    }

 </script>
```

This is my service

```
public class SectionService : ISection
{
    public string Guardar(string name, string title, string scope, string description)
    {
        return "OK";
    }

}
```

This is the Section Interface

```
namespace WcfSection
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISection
    {
      [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
      [OperationContract]
        string Guardar(string name, string title, string scope, string description);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is where I think the problem might be, web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>      
       <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
   </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <services>
   <service name="WcfSection.SectionService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost:52928/"/>
       </baseAddresses>
     </host> 
     <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" contract="WcfSection.ISection"/>
   </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior"  />
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
<compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I wanna add that this is my first attempt to do this, also that the html and service belong to different projects, and I struggled to get through CORS problems just to get to this point. All it does now is showing the 'it doesn't work' alert.

Comment: Its hard to guess why the server is throwing an error. I would use Fiddler, Firebug or the Chrome console to see what the actual response is from the the server. If you use Firebug or Chrome you can find the response in the "Network" tab. You may be able to see a stack trace and get to the root of the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your code on my PC. but it seems at least you need to add  into endpoint behavior.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
      </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```